# Retrieve information from a function used in another application Android

Tags: android

I have an application that have a timer that every x seconds change the textview text with a random number.

```
  @Override                    
public void run() {   
        TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        while(true){
           Random r = new Random();
           int i1 = (r.nextInt(805) + 650);  
           t.setText(i1.toString());                                                            
           try {
               Thread.sleep(i1);
           }catch (Exception e) {
               tv1.setText(e.toString());
           }           
        } 
}
```

I need to create a second application that retrieve the random number "i1" everytime that this number is generated (or everytime that the textview changed text).

Is possible to do so in some way?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/sharing/index.html

Comment: This is so helpfull can you please post this as answer and put an example regarding my specifc case?
I can set it as solved in this way

Answer (score 2):

> I need to create a second application that retrieve the random number "i1" everytime that this number is generated (or everytime that the textview changed text).

This implies two things:

1. The user is not involved in requesting that the data be shared (e.g., there is no button or action bar item or anything)
2. The first application should push the data to the second application (versus the second application pulling the data, as it will not know when the data changed)

The simplest solution would be for the first application to send a broadcast [via `sendBroadcast()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendBroadcast(android.content.Intent)) that is picked up by the second application using [a `BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html). The first application would send the broadcast "everytime that this number is generated (or everytime that the textview changed text)", so the second application has the latest value.

Comment: So in few words is not possible to do it without the "collaboration" of first applcation?

Comment: @AlessioTrecani: Not without security and privacy issues. Apps cannot spy on other apps. The primary way of enabling that sort of spying involves an app implementing an `AccessibilityService`, which requires the user to manually configure it in Settings.

Comment: Oh this is a good informations.. So if I enable AccessibilityService I can retrieve information in my first application? for example "listening"(in some unknown way) for that function.. and everytime it is called I can retrieve the random number?